# Combinatorics and permutations of rankings

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In a country there are 2016 cities. We can draw 4 rankings A1. . . , A4, each order totally all the cities of this nation. Every tourist who comes will choose a ranking Ai and a c town and visit all the cities that, according to Ai, are better than c, eventually deciding whether to go also in c. In the end we want, for every two different cities c and c0, that the number of all the tourists who have visited c is different from the number of all those who have visited c0. What is the minimum number k of tourists with which it is possible to satisfy this condition?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if there are $n$ cities, you need $n$ different numbers of tourists visiting cities.  How many tourists does it take to satisfy that, ignoring the fluff about how they decide which cities to visit?  Now convince yourself that you can get all those numbers with the process described.  In fact, you can do it with all the tourists using the same ranking.

Comment: So with 2016 tourists I can achieve my goal?

Comment: I think you can do one better.  Your first sentence seems to make $2016$ the year, not the number of cities.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've made a mistake. Anyway it seems you've understand the problem correctly. So the answer is 2015 because considering one ranking ignoring how they decide which cities to visit, if I have 2016 cities, I need 2016 tourists, but one will be visited by 0 toursits?

Comment: Yes, you need $2016$ different numbers of tourists, but they can be the range $[0,2015]$.  Then with just one ranking, tourist $k$ visits the top $k-1$ cities.  One poor city gets no visitors.

Comment: But doesn't it change with 4 rankings?

Comment: It depends on how you read the problem.  One way is to allow us to tell the tourists which ranking to use and we can tell them all to use the same one.  Another is that we have to let somebody else make up the rankings and tell each tourist which ranking they will use, then we have to find the maximum minimum number of tourists that must be used over the set of rankings and assignments.  I suspect it is still $2015$ but am not sure.  There might be some correlation between the rankings that means you can't get all the numbers in $[0,2015]$.  I read the problem the first way.

Comment: Why do you say that you suspect it's still 2015?

Comment: Take the case of 4 cities A1=1234 A2=4321 A3=3412 A4=2143 even if k was enormious we will never achiev the gol. Am I right?

Comment: \With five people we could distribute them as evenly as possible, having two use A1 and visit 12, one use A2 and visit 432, one use A3 and visit 3, and one use A4 and visit 21.  I haven't found a solution with fewer, but there may be one.

Comment: I haven't uderstood this solution, could you briefly explain it?

Comment: The first two people are using the first ranking list and choose to visit two cities each.  Following that, they each go to cities 1 and 2.  The third uses the second list and visits thee, and so on.  City 2 gets four visitors, city 1 gets three, city 3 gets 2 and city 4 gets 1.

Comment: Yes there is if they all use one ranking

Comment: But what does you think will happen if we let tourists choose a ranking and a city by theirselves?

Comment: Then you certainly can't guarantee that each city gets a different number of tourists.  They could all visit all the cities, for example.  We have to be able to tell each tourist how many cities to visit.  The question is whether there is some restriction on how the tourists are distributed among the rankings.  If we can have them all use the same ranking, we can guarantee to be able to do $2015$.  If we have to spread them evenly, maybe not, but I don't know.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thank you so much